# Inheritance - are you supposed to use base classes, or are they just a framework for child classes?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Sorry if this has been asked before. I haven't found a distinct answer.

I have two classes, motorbike and car. The only difference is number of wheels and number of passengers allowed.

In this case, would I use motorbike as the base class (and have car be the subclass), or create a new 'vehicle' base class?

Comment: Probably not a _great_ question anywhere, but the best possible home for this sort of question would be https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm sure you can think of more differences between a motorbike and car than the number of wheels and number of passengers allowed. Can you do a `wheelie()` in a car, or `buckleSeatBelt()` in a motorbike. A class has methods as well as state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, inheritance is used to model an "isA" relationship.

A car has similar parts to two motorbikes, but a car is *not* a motorbike.

Both cars and motorbikes, however, are vehicles.

So if it were me, I would use a vehicle class as a base class, and derive both car and motorbike from it.

Answer (score 0):

It would really based on how you define a motorbike and a car.  If all you cared about is 'it has an engine, and can transport people'.  Then a car could be a derived class from motorbike.

But to me that's a pretty silly concept - a car and a motorbike are two distinct things, that share some similar properties, like engine type.  But a motorbike would have no concept of 'number of doors', that's only for cars.

When two things share similar properties, but are fundamentally different, you should opt for a base class (or interfaces) they both inherit from.